# How to fix Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Object' cannot be converted to type 'Function'

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager

I'm getting below error with my `JavaScript` function.

```
Uncaught Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Object' cannot be converted to type 'Function'.
Parameter name: handler
```

**Script Manager**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Navigate() {
        $('#dialogDiv').dialog('open');
    }

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest($(document).ready(function () {
        var list = "";
        $('#dialogDiv').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            width: 300,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    $("#<%=Type_GV.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
                        //Skip first(header) row
                        if (!this.rowIndex) return;
                        var type = $(this).find("td:last").html();
                        list += type + "</br>";
                    });
                    alert(list)
                }
            }
        });
    })
    );
</script>
```

I can remove above error by adding `ScriptMode="Release"` to my Script Manager. but it deos not solve my problem. I have a `gridview` on `JavaScript` and i'm trying to get modified values from `textbox` in `gridview`. but always it gave me the old value. not modified value.

By adding `ScriptMode="Release"` to my Script Manager hide the error. but my problem is not fixed.

I wish to know why i'm getting this error and proper way to fix it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The `remove_endRequest` accepts function that you want to remove from the list of handlers for [endRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). So the code you provided has invalid parameter because call of `$(document).ready()` returns the jQuery "wrapper" object instead of handler function.

If you want to call code after the end of async postback you should use `add_endRequest` and remove `$(document).ready` since it is not tied to the async postback events.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Navigate() {
        $('#dialogDiv').dialog('open');
    }

    function myEndRequestHandler() {
        var list = "";
        $('#dialogDiv').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            width: 300,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    $("#<%=Type_GV.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
                        //Skip first(header) row
                        if (!this.rowIndex) return;
                        var type = $(this).find("td:last").html();
                        list += type + "</br>";
                    });
                    alert(list)
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(myEndRequestHandler);
</script>
```

And when you don't need handle `endRequest` event unsubscribe `myEndRequestHandler` as follows:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest(myEndRequestHandler);
```